# How to generate Circle Shape With Outer Ring

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin, material-design

How to generate views as shown below,

[image]

I tried to adding stroke to cardView(Material cardView) and using it in a recyclerView. I have used multiple views, below is the xml code for the outer ring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <com.google.android.material.circularreveal.cardview.CircularRevealCardView
        android:id="@+id/selectedCardColor"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/app_color_white"
        app:strokeColor="@color/app_color_green"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="28dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

        <com.google.android.material.circularreveal.cardview.CircularRevealCardView
            android:id="@+id/selectedCardInnerColor"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/app_color_green"
            app:cardCornerRadius="28dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="false" />
    </com.google.android.material.circularreveal.cardview.CircularRevealCardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the code for circle shape,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="6dp">

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/unSelectedCardColor"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/app_color_green"
    app:cardCornerRadius="28dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It works only in pie(android 9) and above. Other devices it appears as below,

[image]

The ring should appear on selected views. I should be able to change color programmatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try if it works .....Make a **ring.xml** in your Drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="20dp" android:left="20dp"  android:bottom="20dp"  android:right="20dp" >
        <shape >
            <solid android:color= "#FF0000"/>
            <corners android:radius="300dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item  android:left="40dp"  android:bottom="40dp" android:top="40dp" android:right="40dp"    >
        <shape >
            <solid android:color= "#ffffff"/>

            <corners android:radius="300dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item   android:left="60dp"  android:bottom="60dp" android:right="60dp"  android:top="60dp" >
        <shape >
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#00ffff"
                android:endColor="#0000ff"
                android:angle="90"/>
            <corners android:radius="300dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

please replace the white color with the color of **YOUR BACKGRAOUND**

use it wherever you like.eg as the background of your button

You may change the color of the ring in the first item and change the color of circle shape in the last item.

Comment: Can I change the color programmatically? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Please Try Below code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1RGQ.png)

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:top="5dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:right="5dp" >
    <shape >
        <solid android:color= "#090909"/>
        <corners android:radius="400dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item  android:left="10dp"
    android:bottom="10dp"
    android:top="10dp"
    android:right="10dp">
    <shape >
        <solid android:color= "#ffffff"/>
        <corners android:radius="300dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:left="20dp"
    android:bottom="20dp"
    android:right="20dp"
    android:top="20dp" >
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid
            android:color="#9C27B0"/>
        <size
            android:width="200dp"
            android:height="200dp"/>

    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Can I change the color programmatically? Thanks.